# Trouble understanding a bash command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set up a program and came across this line in a bash script. Could someone tell me what it does? I'm not very experienced with bash.

```
export PS1='\e[0;33mmyProject \e[0;32m\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$\e[0m '
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please give some context, by describing what the complete script is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command does two things. It sets the title of the terminal window, and
sets the bash prompt.

```
export PS1='\e[0;33mmyProject \e[0;32m\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$\e[0m '
```

Piece by piece:

```
export PS1=
```

This sets the PS1 variable, which is contains the bash prompt.

```
\e[0;33m
```

`\e` is translated to the `ESC` character (ascii=0x1B), which is a Control Sequence Introducer, which signifies the beginning of an [ANSI Escape Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). The `m` character at the end of the sequence indicates that the everything between `[` and `m` is to be interpreted as a `;`-separated list of SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) parameters (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) for more information). The `0` clears all previous text formatting, and the `33` sets the text color to yellow.

```
myProject
```

This just adds the string `myProject` to the bash prompt.

```
\e[0;32m
```

This clears all the previous text formatting (0) and sets the text color to green. (32)

```
\[ ... \]
```

`\[` begins a sequence of non-printing characters which ends with `\]`. Everything between those two delimiters will not be visible in the prompt.

```
\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a
```

This sets the title of the terminal window to something like

```
username@hostname: /current/working/directory
```

The next bit:

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}
```

If the variable `$debian_chroot` has been defined, then this expression will evaluate to the value of `$debian_chroot`.

`$debian_chroot` is a variable that is set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372849/what-does-debian-chrootdebian-chroot-do-in-my-terminal-prompt) explains it a lot better than I can.

```
\u@\h:\w\$\e[0m
```

`\u` evaluates to the username of the current user, `\h` evaluates to the name of the computer, and `\w` evaluates to the current working directory. `\$` is just the character `$`. It needs to be escaped because in bash script, the character `$` signifies that the following characters are the name of a variable. `\e[0m` reverts the text formatting back to default.

An image of what the prompt might look like in a terminal: [image: What it would might like in a terminal]

Comment: This is great! Thank you for providing such a detailed explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a complicated command you have here!

Let's break it down section by section.

```
export
```

This means that we are setting a variable to be used in other programs.

```
PS1=
```

The name of the variable is PS1.

```
\e
```

This is an escaped character. In bash (and most programming languages), Everything with a backslash before it is an escaped character. It is used for when you need to include a control character like a space, or the control key itself in a string. When it's escaped, bash treats it like it's part of the string, and not another control character.

```
[
```

This is the start of an array. It's very similar to an array in a C program.

```
;
```

This is an end character, it can mean several different things. Here, it's being used to define part of the array.

There is some other stuff here, but it's mostly just data in the array.

```
:
```

This is a NOT operand. It is used to determine the inverse of something.

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}
```

This is a variable. In bash, variables start with a $.

It is using the variable debian_chroot and adding it to itself if it's not null.

This command is just defining a variable, in this case an array containing information probably about a chroot with a debian install in it.

Comment: `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` does not actually do that, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/372849/what-does-debian-chrootdebian-chroot-do-in-my-terminal-prompt